# I cannot collapse message tree in thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I,ve sorted my inbox in thunderbird (V 11.0.1) by date and grouped them by sort.  When I collapse the groups, they colapse.  If I go to another account inbox or other folder such as trash, the inbox is no longer collapsed.
Cannot find a way to solve this.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled thunderbird - same as before.

Mozilla forum has no answers.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Anthony

Comment: Which OS? Works for me in OS X Lion and I haven't made any changes relevant to this. Also -- reinstalling Thunderbird may not help, as typically user settings are preserved.

Comment: I'm using windows 7

Comment: You may want to add that to the question. Also, try the Thunderbird forums at http://forums.mozillazine.org/